# Group Column With Same Value Into One Row (JSON Output)

Tags: php, sql, json

I am using PHP to output some SQL code and then returning the data from a JSON to Ajax and then populating a dropdown from it. The idea is to have a cable number dropdown show up multiple options if the data is nearby within a radius, but the issue I am having is it is showing the same values like 6 times if there are 6 options within that radius... For example, what SHOULD happen is a cable number 1000 with section 1,2,3,4 and 5 and cable number 1001 with section numbers 1,2,3 and 4 are within a 50 ft radius, therefore only cable numbers 1000 and 1001 should be in the dropdown and the section numbers are handled differently (irrelvant to this question)... Problem is the drop down will show cable number 1000 five times (as many section numbers for that cable number in DB) and likewise for the 1001 cable number, displayed four times, so now I have 9 cable numbers in the dropdown all the same number. How can I get my php/sql to only display just the two cable numbers, and have it not show up 9 times?

I believe the culprit to this behavior is because the HAVING DISTANCE and the radius are all different, so since there are different distance columns, then the distances populate with the same cable number for each row...

SQL

```
// Define JSON array
$array = array();

$sql = <<<EOD
SELECT DISTINCT cable_no,
       3959.0 * 5280.0 * acos(sin(radians($lat)) * sin(radians(extraction_worksheet.mh_lat_a))
       + cos(radians($lat)) * cos(radians(extraction_worksheet.mh_lat_a))
       * cos(radians(extraction_worksheet.mh_long_a) - radians($lon))) as distance
 FROM extraction_worksheet
 WHERE extraction_worksheet.mh_lat_a != ''
 HAVING distance <= $radius
EOD;

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error'.mysql_error());

// If DB query successful then send data to calling routine.
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $array[] = $row;
    }   
        print json_encode($array);
```

JS

```
function populate_cableno(latitude, longitude, radius) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: './php/getcable_number.php',
    data: 'latitude=' + latitude + '&longitude=' + longitude + '&radius=' + radius,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (mydata) {

        if (mydata.length >= 1) {
            if (mydata.length > 1) {
                $("#cable_no")
                    .replaceWith('<select onchange="get_co_name(); get_section_no(); return false;" id="cable_no" name="cable_no"></select>');

                var combo = document.getElementById("cable_no");

                while (combo.firstChild) {
                    combo.removeChild(combo.firstChild);
                };

                var option = document.createElement("option");

                for (var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
                    option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.text = mydata[i]['cable_no'];
                    option.value = mydata[i]['cable_no'];
                    try {
                        combo.add(option, null); //Standard
                    } catch (error) {
                        combo.add(option); // IE only
                    }
                };
                get_co_name();
                get_section_no();
            }
            else {
                document.forms['prepform'].elements['cable_no'].value = mydata[0]['cable_no'];
                get_co_name();
                get_section_no();
            }
        } else {
            alert("There are no cables within a 2000ft radius.");
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error...");
    },
    complete: function () {}
});
};
```

Comment: First verify where the problem lies, your SQL/PHP code looks good, but to be sure check if returned JSON have 9 entries - it is possible that something is messed up on JS part that populates drop-downs.

Comment: Ok added JS bit... but when I run the php file alone, it returns multiple cable numbers with the same cable number. I want the output of the SQL to just return 1 cable number if there are more than one of the same type...

Comment: When I run the query, I get a distance column returned along with my cable numbers column... I only want the cable numbers to be returned in my select statement and I am not sure why the distance column automatically is inserted with the cable number column... The database needs to automatically find the radius and then come up with the corresponding cable numbers only, so it seems my SQL isn't doing what I want it to and not sure how to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well I ended up finding that adding "GROUP BY cable_no" before HAVING DISTANCE was what did the trick. Thanks.